# Can i make an HTTP Request module return a custom error response?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule-component, mule4

There are two APIs. API1 calls API2 through an HTTP Requester. API2 has a flow with a custom "CS:INVALID_USER" Raise Error and throws the error. The error is handled by the global error handler (propagate) in API2. When the error returns to the API1 Http Request module, the error is now different. It now shows HTTP:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR. I'm guessing it's because the custom error is only defined in API2 but i'm not sure. Is it possible to have the http requester receive the initial INVALID_USER error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that errors only exist in the Mule application that raises them. The communication between both applications is through the HTTP protocol, so by default you will get an HTTP error in the client application, because the other application has to return an HTTP error. Explicitly if the error handling sets it, or implicit if not handled.

Either return some appropriate HTTP error or return a payload that contains the error details. The client application has to be prepared to interpret the response appropriately.

Comment: Specifically, CS:INVALID_USER might represent bad input from the requester, and API2 could respond with 400 Bad Request. Or, it might represent a problem inside API2, in which case a 500 Internal Server Error is appropriate.   Assuming 400 Bad Request, API1 HTTP Requester can have an Error Mapping that translates HTTP:BAD_REQUEST to an application defined error like API1:INVALID_INPUT and then use an error scope like On Error Continue to determine that the user was bad and generate an appropriate response for its consumer.