# Error propagation from system to process to experience APIs in Mule 4

Tags: error-handling, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

1. The system API throws an error - ERROR:TYPE_1 with status code 401.
2. The process API should give the same error.
3. The experience API should give the same error.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72266871/can-i-make-an-http-request-module-return-a-custom-error-response

Answer (score 0):

In the the process API you can write something like this

```
<flow name="error_flow">
  <raise-error doc:name="raise-error" type="ERROR:TYPE_1" description="401 error ocurred">
    <error-handler>
      <on-error-continue enableNotification="true" type="ERROR:TYPE_1" doc:name ="on error continue" doc:id="on-error-continue">
    // here you can write a dwl which gives you a payload like 
    // {
    
       "errorCode"  : 401
       "errorType" : "ERROR:TYPE_1"
          }
      <on-error-continue>
    </error-handler>
```

This payload will reach to your experience layer.